# What is the best HTML layout technique? DIVs vs Tables

Tags: html, css, html-table

I find using tables as the backbone easier to manipulate, specially when aligning things vertically. But I only seem to find code samples using DIV with heaps of CSS that looks like hacks into the inner workings of CSS.

Comment: short: DO NOT USE TABLE!

Comment: never ever use the table.

Comment: Sounds like you might like to checkout flexbox. Table layouts were always a hack.

Comment: But we can use table when either client request or when you are going to show tabular data with some condition.

Comment: `<div>` structure is best `<table>` is not that flexible..so use div

Comment: Using `<div>` is better one, as tables are heavy to load.

Comment: Agree w Rafael. I did heavy web full-stack 15 years ago when CSS was budding. Tables did everything before CSS.  I program in many languages and i wanted to fall in love with CSS 100% and for the most part it's very cool but honestly when it comes to doing simple things like true dynamic alignment on the screen or within a parent item you can find dozens of solutions saying how "Easy" it is but only 1 or 2 of them actually work and the CSS is just plain foreign and require bloated header/trailing divs looking more like a work around than what everybody claimed tables were.

Answer (score 2):

**Using `<table>` for layout is considered a hack.**

Layouts used to be done with `<table>` a long time ago before CSS was around. Nowadays, it common practice to separate out the **structure, styling, and behavior** of your project into **HTML, CSS, and JavaScript**, respectively.

With HTML5, there has been a push for using semantic tags such as `<article>`, `<section>`, and so on in place of `<div>`. Nonetheless, `<div>` is still fine and 100% preferable over `<table>` unless you're specifically working with tabular data. Even then, the actual layout styling should still take place in your CSS.

Answer (score 1):

current best practices is to use `<div>` instead of `<table>` for layout.

main reasons are:

- `<table>` are inflexible, in the sense that a table layout is embedded in the html structure of the `table` element and his childs (ie `<tr><td>`)
- `<div>` allows lots of freedom on layout with css regardless of their html structure
- `<table>` layout can be easly achieved using  with css

note that for tabular data the best practice is to use `<table>`

also note that semantic `HTML5` elements like `<header>` `<nav>` `<article>` `<section>` `<footer>` are consider a better choice for markup than `<div>`

Answer (score 0):

`<table>` is an HTML element that should be used to display formatted data, tabular data. We used it to make web layouts, but we tried to stop it 15 years ago.

**Why ?**

*Because `<table>` is not designed to make website layouts, just to display and sort data (that's logically what a table would do). But CSS is. CSS can provide you many ways to think your layout: box model, flexbox, and some stuff like `display: table` that you should find useful.*

**Remember : HTML provides and structures data, CSS puts the style.**

Answer (score 0):

Back in days when there was no CSS3 and flexbox tables layouts was good because it' provided most of modern css functionality.

Modern programmers uses `<div>` and CSS3 and/or flexbox.

Currently when we have HTML5 even `<div>` is not so good solution as all elements in your page has some meaning. Now we have elements like `<nav>`, `<section>`, `<aside>` and [much more](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element)

*Don't use table for layout as it has different meaning than div, and you can achieve same (or maybe better) results with CSS*